# Not able to update values of an Mlab document using mongoose, it is getting saved as "__v": 0

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose, mlab

I am new to node and mongoDb,
I have a mongo db account where i created a collection called "dbTestData"

[image: My Mongo DB Screen Shot]

I am trying to create CRUD operation using node express mongoose and express,
and i am using postman to get post update and delete values to mlab db.

My Get call is working fine, but when i try to post values in Json like,

[image]

i am getting success message , but when i check the db it is saved as

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c3ad1c19bc5932f800d26f7"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

My app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const dbTestData=require('./models/post')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://<userName>:<password>@ds221242.mlab.com:21242/kiitasklist").then(()=>{
  console.log("hello");
}).catch(
  ()=>{
    console.log("heee");
  });

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.post("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new dbTestData({
      id:req.body.id,
      name:req.body.name
    });
    post.save().then(documents=>{
      console.log(post);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post added successfully'
      });
    });
  });


app.get("/api/posts",(req,res,next)=>{
  dbTestData.find().then(documents=>{
  res.status(200).json({
    message:'Posts fetched successful',
    posts:documents
    });
});
});


app.put("/api/posts/:id",(req,res,next)=>{
  const post = new dbTestData({
    _id:req.body._id,
    name:req.body.name
  });
  dbTestData.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},post).then(result=>{
    res.status(200).json({message:"update successfully"});
  });
});

app.delete("/api/posts/:id",(req,res,next)=>{
  dbTestData.deleteOne({_id:req.params.id}).then(documents=>{
     res.status(200).json({
       message:'posts fetched successful',
       posts:documents
     });
   });
});

module.exports = app;
```

My Server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./api/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

My post.js where i have created the mongoose schema

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
module.exports= mongoose.model("dbTestData", new Schema({}), "DbTestData");
```

both the get and delete works ,
But the post and put is not happening properly, it returns a success message in my console but empty value like

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c3ad1c19bc5932f800d26f7"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

is saved during POST and nothing happens during PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To  solve this post issue

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

PostSchema = new Schema({
 id:Number,
 name: String
});
// the compile the model using mongoos model function giving the schema u created
const Post = module.exports= mongoose.model("dbTestData", PostSchema, "DbTestData");
```

after that in your post req do it like this

```
//before posting you need to require the model first 
const Post = require('./models/post'); // your post.js
app.Post("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
    const post = new Post({
      id:req.body.id,
      name:req.body.name
    });
    post.save().then(documents=>{
      console.log(post);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post added successfully'
      });
    });
  });
```

make sure you create/define your schema correctly in order to save data using it.
after that put is the same the way u did it should work fine after u define your schema correctly

and  finally try this also. make sure you add these tow line the exact same way I have given in your case you have made them switched

```
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: oh Thanks for that , i haven't created my schema properly, im just using an empty schema , it works fine now after adding the schema .

Comment: Any idea on restricting the _v on every POST, or PUT ??

Comment: well you can suppress it but don't do it.. They recomment that you don't tamper with mongoose built in things.. actually this _v is there to make version validations when updating mongoose.. So don't worry about it it won't effect to your application

Comment: if you found this was helpful, vote the answer by clicking up arrow as well  :)